# create-react-app default project won't start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Using create-react-app is very simple yes?

Simply...

```
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

Only for some reason when I do so lately, npm start only yields the following error:

```
./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in '/Users/username/test/my-app/node_modules/react-dom/lib
```

This is the default project. Shouldn't it pull all of its own dependencies?

I've tried with npm versions (in order) 3.9, 5.2, 3.10, and 4.6.1. All give the same error, with the exception of 5.2 which gave some similar error but related to es-lint. Searches indicated that npm 5 is a buggy mess, so I went to 4 and came up with the same error again.

What am I missing?

Comment: That is indeed odd, because I can't reproduce it. I'm using node 6.10.1 and npm 3.10.10. Have you tried `npm install` on your project?

Comment: Did you try creating a new project after you switched npm versions?

Comment: I've tried an additional npm install with no change, and I always create a brand new project after switching versions. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled react -g after a couple of npm version changes as well. I'm on node v7.2.0. Maybe back that up to 6.10.1?

Comment: I will also add that I tried this on a different machine with the exact same results. npm 3.10.9, node 6.9.1